# ComparisonFailure - Can't See Physical Difference

Tags: java, junit

I'm running some JUnit tests and I ran into a ComparisonFailure, but I cannot understand why because my actual and expected look exactly alike.

```
correctline = "   The following  quotation about writing  test programs for  a document" + "\n";
```

My assertequals statement is:

```
assertEquals("wrong contents: line", correctline, output.toString());
```

The error is.

```
wrong contents: line expected:<...rams for  a document[]
```

> but was:<...rams for  a document[

```
]
```

Comment: do `assertEquals("wrong contents: printer", correctline.trim(), output.toString());`

Answer (score 2):

The 3 spaces at the front of `correctline` appear to be the difference.  If they're important, then your test has told you that `output.toString()` is wrong.  If they're not important, then  either remove the spaces from `correctline` or place calls to [`trim()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#trim%28%29) to make whitespace at the beginning or end not matter:

```
assertEquals("wrong contents: printer", correctline.trim(),
    output.toString().trim());
```

Comment: If they're not important, consider [Matchers.equalToIgnoringWhiteSpace](http://hamcrest.org/JavaHamcrest/javadoc/1.3/org/hamcrest/Matchers.html#equalToIgnoringWhiteSpace%28java.lang.String%29) to make the assertion clearer.

Comment: Note that the square braces indicate the difference, so it's the white space at the *end* of the string that's different.

Answer (score 0):

It could be different white space at the end of the line. To be certain, put a breakpoint before the assertion and eyeball the expected and actual strings in the debugger- that will be a lot quicker than trying several guesses and re-running the test each time until you get it right.